# Language not switching to french on Leaflet Routing Machine

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

I'm using this  [plugin](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine) , I want to set language as French **fr**, for that I use `formatter: new L.Routing.Formatter(language: 'fr')` like you can see the code bellow :

```
L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: [L.latLng(48.8534, 2.3488), L.latLng(44.837789, -0.57918)],
  routeWhileDragging: true,
  show: true,
  formatter: new L.Routing.Formatter({ units: 'metric', language: 'fr' }),
  autoRoute: true
}).addTo(this.mapInstance);
```

But, the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVhJ6.png) is always in English 'en'.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this :

- First, add localization.js to your other scripts in angular.json file, like that:

```
 "scripts": [
              "node_modules/leaflet-routing-machine/src/localization.js" 
            ]
```

- Then, add the option **language : 'fr'** to your Routing control as bellow :

```
 L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [
        L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
        L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
      ],
      collapsible: true, // hide/show panel routing
      autoRoute: true, // possibility to take autoRoute
      language : 'fr', // < --- THIS IS ESPECIALLY WHAT YOU SHOULD ADD
      // ...
    }).addTo(this.map);
```